# Trying to compare each separate item in an array to detect a number in a user inputted password for a password checker. How would I do this?

Tags: python, arrays

This is all I have so far:

```
UI= raw_input("Please enter a password")
array=list(UI)
UIs=len(UI)
n=0
s=0
number=("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0")
symbol= ("@",",",".","'","!","_","-","~","#","+","=")
print array
    if array==number:
        n=1
print n
```

I`m fairly new to programming and here is the brief states to check if the password contains numbers

Comment: `if any(c.isdigit() for c in UI): print('UI contains >=1 number digit')`

Comment: Hi Josh. A string is an iterable in python, so you can just use `in` to check the original string `UI` for what it contains. I would suggest iterating over `number` there, or iterating over the password and checking each letter with `isnumeric()` Alternatively, you can start learning about regex - `import re` 
I also echo the point about using Python 3.x

Comment: if you're new to programming, you should start with python 3

Comment: Are you trying to detect if the whole password contains only digits or if there is a digit within?

Comment: As a heads up, instead of `n=1` and `n=0` you could use `n=True` and `n=False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it.  You can iterate over each letter in the input and check if it is a digit.

Also, you should use Python 3 if you are just starting to learn.

```
UI= input("Please enter a password")
n = 0
for char in UI:
    if char.isdigit():
        n += 1
print(n)
```